# Entity Framework Database First Classes and Table Names

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am trying to add .edmx to my web api application.  The table names in our database are long and cumbersome like tbl_Company, tbl_User_Logins, tbl_Company_Departments.  I would like to use neat class names like Company, User, Departments that map to these tables.  I have been trying to find sample code to do this, but I feel like I am not "asking the right questions" which is why I can't find any answer.

I tried creating classes for "Department" and "User", and I tried adding code like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("tbl_Company_Departments_xlu");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("tbl_User_Logins");
}
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

but it didn't work when I tried to add a new department using `Departments.Add(department)`.  I am obviously missing a step, but I do not know what it is.  I am new to this and am struggling.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free coders resource. You can  create code first dbcontext just for 2 tables, even if you have edmx for another tables, but you have to make some reseach.  Create classes, define relations, add dbcontext dependancy injection , migrate classes to data base tables and so on. But you have to make some recearch and create the code. Only after this, if you have problems you can ask  a question here. One more time - nobody will work for you for free here. Trere are a lot of freelance resources, where you can post your offer.

Comment: *it didn't work* - what **exactly** didn't work? Did you get an error - if so, ***what error***? Did you get no data inserted at all? Wrong data? Wrong how?? Just saying *didn't work* doesn't give us anything to go on, really ....

Comment: Rename the classes in the EDMX designer. Or, better, don't use EDMX (= database-first) and start working code-first. You can't mix both modes.

Comment: @marc_s - it gives me the error that Departments is not part of the Context.

Comment: @Gert Arnold - I may be going about this in the wrong way.  I'm going to do some more research on the "Code First" approach and see if that will work better for me.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Serge - I did not ask you or anyone else to "work for free".  I thought I might have been missing a simple step.  You personally know that I did a LOT of work in regards to this issue because I showed it all to you.  And the last that I checked "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."